# Natural frequencies of a transfer function

Tags: filters, transfer-function

I have been told in the university that the natural frequencies (also called $\textit{eigenfrequencies}$) are the poles of the transfer function, however, Matlab compute them as the modulus of the pole (information taken from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/damp.html)).

So the real question is, are the natural frequencies complex numbers or real numbers measured in rad/s?

Comment: it might depend on whether it's the $s$-plane or the $z$-plane.

i haven't heard it called *"natural frequency"*, but usually i hear it referred to as *"**resonant** frequency"*.  even so, the frequency of ringing is not exactly the same as that but gets closer as the *"resonance"* or the $Q$ of a resonant system gets large.  if that's the case, the resonant frequency and the ringing frequency is about the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [natural frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_frequency) is a real number, and Matlab computes it correctly by taking the magnitude of the (complex-valued) pole.

As an example, the denominator of the transfer function of a second-order continuous-time system is given by

$$D(s)=s^2+2\omega_n\zeta s+\omega_n^2\tag{1}$$

where $\zeta$ is the [damping ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio), and $\omega_n$ is the natural frequency. The poles are given by the roots of $(1)$. Assuming an underdamped system ($\zeta<1)$, the poles are given by

$$s_{\infty}=-\omega_n\left(\zeta\pm j\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

from which we get

$$|s_{\infty}|^2=\omega_n^2\left[\zeta^2+(1-\zeta^2)\right]=\omega_n^2\tag{3}$$

So the natural frequency $\omega_n$ is given by the magnitude of the pole $s_{\infty}$.

Note that the natural frequency $\omega_n$ is not the actual oscillation frequency unless there is no damping (i.e., $\zeta=0$).